# truncate в DetailView

Tags: php, yii2, виджет

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать функцию truncate в виджете DetailView? В GridView разобрался, вот так делал:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'attribute' => 'description',
            'options' => ['style' => 'height:200px'],
            'value' => function ($model) {
                return StringHelper::truncate($model->description, 300);
            }
        ],
```

все работало, но если сделать так в DetailView, то не работает. Ошибку пишет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `DetailView` нужно передавать не `callback`, а непосредственно значение атрибута.

Например:

```
'value' => StringHelper::truncate($model->description, 300)
```

Comment: То что нужно. Большое спасибо!